# How to set bangla text (other then english text) as codeigniter session value?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to set codeigniter session value as like follows

```
$prescription_data="খাওয়ার ৩০ মিনিট আগে খাবেন";
$this->session->set_userdata("test_session",$prescription_data);
```

But It automatically kill my session. It automatically log out. If I use

```
$prescription_data="this is test";
$this->session->set_userdata("test_session",$prescription_data);
```

This work fine. Can any one help me? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: whats problem with english session

Comment: Nothing going wrong with English text

Comment: $prescription_data="খাওয়ার ৩০ মিনিট আগে খাবেন";
$this->session->set_userdata("test_session",$prescription_data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue has been solved.

Unfortunately my session table user_data field collation was not utf8_unicode. Thats why the data was being lost when submitted. Since it is using the ci_session table. Its working now nicely.

[Session issue in codeigniter for arabic character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278339/session-issue-in-codeigniter-for-arabic-character)